# Initialize char* at the time of declaration using new operator

Tags: c++, c++11

The c++ code

```
char *ptr=new char("char_pointer_initialization");
```

throws

> ```
> error Invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
> ```

How can I fix that?

Comment: `std::string` ?

Comment: What's your question? Please also provide a compilable [MCVE].

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
char *ptr=new char("char_pointer_initialization");
```

Tries to allocate a single `char` and initialize it with a `const char*`, hence the error message.

Unlike as a declaration without `new`

```
char arr[] = "char_pointer_initialization";
```

the only way to use inline initialization for the `char` array using `new` is to write

```
char *ptr=new char[40]{ 'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', '_', 'p', ..., '\0' };
```

See a [working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fc11f56f62ca38d).

---

I'd recommend to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead, so you can simply write

```
std::string s = "char_pointer_initialization";
```

if you need a `const char*` you can use the `std::string::c_str()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up about new expressions. If you have something like

```
new type(value)
```

This means

1. Allocate a single object of the given type and
2. Initialize it with the given value

In your case you have

```
new char("char_pointer_initialization");
```

So you are trying to allocate a single char and initialise it with "char_pointer_initialization" which is a pointer to const char. This is why you gat an `invalid conversion from cost char* to char` error.

Other than using std::string, to fix your problem you would need to use the array version of operator new (`new []`) and then copy the string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.